# CASE and CONCAT to create a new String

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble figuring out how to run a good query for the following:

Need to concat the Char and int values to make a new ComponentStored column,

```
"Inventory" Table"
| Component | Storage | ComponentStored
| -------- | -------- |
| 'ALPHA'   | 13429   | 'ALP-1349'
| 'BETA'   | hi-2436  | 'BET-hi-2436'
```

however it can only be for the the two options above

I wrote my current sql with the following intention;

"

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, 
CASE ComponentStored
    WHEN 'ALPHA' THEN 'ALP-' + LTRIM(STR(Component))
    WHEN 'BETA' THEN 'ALP-' + LTRIM(STR(Component))
    ELSE Component
```

however when i close the query the error seems to always point to the case having a Boolean operator?
Hopefully i can discover a smoother solution.

Thanks for any assitance!!!

Tried

```
SELECT Component, StorageLocation, 
CASE NEW COL
    WHEN 'ALPHA' THEN 'ALP-' 
    WHEN 'BETA' THEN 'BETA-' 
    ELSE Component
END
```

expected

```
| Component | Combined column |
| -------- | -------- |
| ALPHA   | ALP-12304   |
| BETA  | BET-D3892   |
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the query editor / designer, it has numerous parsing and display issues... just write your query in a SSMS query window.

Presumably you are after something like

```
select case when component in ('Alpha','Beta') 
  then Concat(left(Component,3), '-', Storage) 
  else Component end as ComponentStored
```

Comment: Thanks! Wasnt aware the editor had display issues. Is there a way, with the solution you provided, to isolate only those marked in my example out of all the column (so without let say DELTA as such). Im assuming using the case still? Sorry i may have missed this out!

Comment: What do you want ComponentStored to be when the value is not ALPHA or BETA?  Basically a CASE expression or simple IIF will work: IIF(Component IN ('ALPHA', 'BETA'), CONCAT(LEFT(Component,3), '-', Storage), 'Not Defined') AS ComponentStored

Comment: @MatthewStanley I've made an edit above, is that now what you're after?

Comment: Yes thanks, providing i could make just those particular strings become a new concat while not editing other strings (coded for some and not others). This seems to work but will check my other DBs too.